# How to consume REST API (Liverail) via webservice using Java

Tags: api, liverail

I am a complete newbie to webservices but have some experience in Java. We have been provided with Liverail API documentation with a list of Entities that we can consume. This is what their doc says:

"Logical flow An API client must always use the /login method followed by the /set/entity method. All the remaining APIcalls will be executed on the selected entity. If you need to switch the current entity, you should use /unset/entity followed by a new /set/entity with the new entity ID as parameter. It is also recommended to call /logout once the API client ends its execution"

XML response format
The LiveRail API XML response is always formated like bellow.

My dilema is that i dont know how to make the GET calls.

What i would like to do in java is :

1. Create a http login to API webservices
2. Fetch a list of data (response is in XML format)
   3 Convert this XML response into CSV file.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: i have an example of xml from internet but dont know how to attach it here.

Comment: solved! thanks. will put up the answer asap!

Answer (score 1):

Why not using RestTemplate?

```
final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employees/{id}";

Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("id", "1");

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
EmployeeVO result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, EmployeeVO.class, params);

System.out.println(result);
```

Here is for more tutorials http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/02/20/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/